# How to switch 4 images using a button

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>How To Insert an Image</title>
<script> 

function changeImage(){
var img = document.getElementById('image');
image.src='image4.jpg';
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="image1.jpg" />

<br><br><br>
<button id="clickme" onclick="changeImage();">Click to change image!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I am quite new to Javascript so please dont be too harsh. Basically im trying to switch from one picture to another using a button. So far with this code i have only managed to do 2 images but when i try to add a 3rd or 4th the first image messess up. I was hoping if someone could help me fix this problem.

Comment: Your example is ok. What happens when you want to use other images? Please, explain more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's simplest approach the I used before, for two images. Easily extended to accomodate three, four, or more alternate images.

```
<div id="image1">
  <img ... >
  <button ...>
</div>
<div id="image2" style="display: none">
   <img ... >
   <button ...>
</div>
```

That is, put the first image, and a button, inside a "< div >" element, and a second image, and a button inside a second "< div >" element that's initially hidden.

Then, each button's javascript simply needs to set its own `div`'s CSS style to "display: none", and remove this style from the other `div` element, effectively hiding one image, and displaying the other one.

This approach also makes it possible to update the button's text or label, accordingly. If both buttons have the same label, the only apparent result is the image change.

Comment: Could you please incorporate that code into mine so i know what im doing because as i said im very new to javascript. Thanks

Comment: It seems that you're on the wrong web site. This is not the web site where you get someone else to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script block instead:

```
<script>

var images = ['image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image1.jpg']

function changeImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById( 'image' )
    var url = images.shift() // remove first url from list
    image.src = url // use it
    images.push( url ) // append url to the end of the list
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. Coould you please incorporate that script block into my code and then show so i can test it. I have put it into my code but it doesnt seem to be working so could you put it into my code so i can test it properly because as i said im new to javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You were very close! You just made mistake to assign a value to `image.src` instead of `img.src`. have a look at the code below :)

Using clicks:

```html
<html> 
<head> 
<title>How To Insert an Image</title>
<script> 
    i = 1; /*Default value, only executed when the page is loaded (default is the first image, so when i + 1 the second image is displayed on first click.)*/
    
function changeImage(){
    var img = document.getElementById('image');
    i = i + 1; /*next image*/
        
       if(i == 5) /* if end is reached, reset to first image*/
        {
            i = 1;
        }

        img.src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image' + i + '.jpg'; /*number to text in variable, so image + 'number of the image (i)' + extension(.jpg in this case)*/
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" height="100px" />

<br><br><br>
<button id="clickme" onclick="changeImage();">Click to change image!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Automatic image slider

```html
<html> 
<head> 
<title>How To Insert an Image</title>
<script> 
    i = 1; /*Default value, only executed when the page is loaded (default is the first image, so when i + 1 the second image is displayed on first click.)*/
    
setInterval(function changeImage(){
    var img = document.getElementById('image');
    i = i + 1; /*next image*/
        
       if(i == 5) /* if end is reached, reset to first image*/
        {
            i = 1;
        }

        img.src='image' + i + '.jpg'; /*number to text in variable, so image + 'number of the image (i)' + extension(.jpg in this case)*/
    }, 5000)

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="image1.jpg" height="100px" />



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would i then using that code incorporate 4 images so it switches 4 images instead of 2. Sorry about this but im still new and this all seems a bit complicated

Comment: have a look at the updated code, if you still have questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: I have seen that i dont know how to do 4 pictures. I completely now understand how to do 2 because of your help so thank you very much. But again how would i then do 4 images. I would be very grateful if you could then upload the code that fixes this problem. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the code again, it now works(and is most definitely the most efficient way) with 4 images and has explaination :) if my solution worked, please upvote my post and mark as answer so others can have benefits of this too.

Comment: Thank you for sticking by me even though im new and helping me through my problem

Comment: I also saw you wanted it to be timed, check out the second snippet

Comment: How would i just use image1, image2, image3, imag4 instead of your http image

Comment: Like in the second snippet, the second snippet should fullfill your needs

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is declare an array which contains all your image urls:

```
var imageUrls = ["image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image1.jpg"];
```

Then when clicking the button, you remove the first image url from the the array by using [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and assign that to variable `imageUrl`.
Then you set that `imageUrl` to the `src` attribute of the image element on your page.
Then you add that `imageUrl` at the end of the array using [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

This will rotate the images in the `imageUrls` array on every click.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>How To Insert an Image</title>
    <script>

        var imageUrls = ["image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image1.jpg"];
        function changeImage(){
            var img = document.getElementById('image');
            var imageUrl = imageUrls.shift();
            img.src = imageUrl;
            imageUrls.push(imageUrl);
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="image1.jpg" />

<br><br><br>
<button id="clickme" onclick="changeImage();">Click to change image!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this has fixed a problem i have been trying to solve for a couple of weeks! Once again thank you so much

Comment: One last question, how would i set a timer so after lets say 5 seconds it changes the image to the next one and so on?

Comment: You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) or [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).